# Checkbox material design no aparece

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, material-design, material

Estoy intentando añadir el CDN de material design de https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design, pero al añadirlo, no me aparece en la checkbox. Me aparece todo en material design menos la checkbox, que no aparece.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/material-fullpalette.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/css/ripples.min.css">


    <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                        <li>
                            <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                         document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                Logout
                            </a>

                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    $.material.init();
  </script>
  <script>
    $.material.checkbox();
  </script>
    <script src"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
    <script src"https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Es para un sitio ecommerce. Adjunto también una captura de como se ve. Muchas gracias a todos.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falta el signo `=` en `<script src"..."></script>` y luego prueba a cambiar el orden:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>      
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-material-design/0.3.0/js/ripples.min.js"></script>    
<script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>

<!-- Init Material-Design -->
<script>
    $.material.init();
    $.material.checkbox();
</script>
```

Comment: Ups! Vaya fallo! Muchísimas gracias!!